# UIWindow layout issue on ios7.1 with xcode 6.0

Tags: xcode6, ios7.1, uiwindow

I created a project on xcode 6.0 and I've been running the project on ios8 simulator however when I tried run it on iphone5s ios7.1 simulator the UIWindow frame became to 320x480...

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

above is how I create UIwindow

[image]

What shall I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must add correct size iphone/ipad default images, your problem will be solved. , see this link for further details [Launch images screen size for iphone](http://www.idev101.com/code/User_Interface/launchImages.html)

Comment: Thanks for reply, but uiwindow can correct layout on iphone5s 8.0 without launch image, and other projects can run on iphone5s ios7.1 without any problem...

Comment: please see you don t have default images in your project

Comment: thanks, I tried and it works, why I don't need before?

Comment: because before you have did not create empty project, when you create an empty project , it don t include default images.

Comment: soooooo goooooood answer~ buddy! Thank you!

Comment: maybe you can help  on another problem cos I think it belongs to the empty project problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26294233/ios7-1-prefix-pch-not-work